# retrieve dependency jar file from gradle api plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

So I'm making a gradle plugin from java,
and one of my goal is to add more dependencies from the content of a dependency

for example in dependency A, And I know the dependency have dependency.json in the jar file.
So I want to read the dependency.json and add dependencies based on the content of the file.
But how can I retrieve the jar of the dependency A?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out a way to retrieve jar.
Using configuration, add dependency to the configuration and use `Configuration.files(Dependency...)` works!